# 2 dimensional array in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, multidimensional-array, nsmutablearray

I get image and imageTitle from JSON like below

```
//geting imageTitle
NSString*titles =[dealPosted valueForKey:@"deaTitle"];
NSLog(@"titles^^^%@",titles);
[titlearray addObject:titles]; 

//geting Images
NSString *geting2 =[diction2 valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
NSData *getdata2=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:geting2]];
NSLog(@"good day2 %@",getdata2);
dataimages2=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata2];
[secondarray addObject:dataimages2];
```

and then i pass them into  UITableViewCell like this

```
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [secondarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.nameLabel.text = [titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But this needs to use two mutablearray . I think it will take much size.So Please any one tell me  how to using Single Array in this case (like two Dimension array) .

Please help me .

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dataDic  =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    NSString*titles =[dealPosted valueForKey:@"deaTitle"];
    [dataDic setValue:titles forKey:@"deaTitle"];


    NSString *geting2 =[diction2 valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
    NSData *getdata2=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:geting2]];
    NSLog(@"good day2 %@",getdata2);
    dataimages2=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata2];
    [dataDic setValue:dataimages2 forKey:@"dealimage"];

    [titlearray addObject:titles];
```

and pass them into UITableViewCell like this, then your issue is solved

```
  cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [[titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [[titlearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"deaTitle"];
```

Comment: This post will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can set these two values in one array one after another(for each image). And then can access them as indexPath.row*2.

```
//geting imageTitle
NSString*titles =[dealPosted valueForKey:@"deaTitle"];
            NSLog(@"titles^^^%@",titles);
            [myArray addObject:titles]; 
 //geting Images
NSString *geting2 =[diction2 valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
            NSData *getdata2=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:geting2]];
            NSLog(@"good day2 %@",getdata2);
            dataimages2=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata2];
            [myArray addObject:dataimages2];
```

Now in table delegate method `numberOfRowsInSection: return myArray.count/2`

and in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [myArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2)+1];
        cell.nameLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2];
```

I am answering you this just because you asked to it using one array but actually it doesn't make any affect in your memory either by using single 2D array, single 1D array with all information or 2 separate 1D arrays.

Comment: thanks for Reply. I  tried as u send but get this error "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75d70e0"

Comment: @iosstart At which line? Because this error does not make any sense here.

Comment: this two lines cell.thumbnailImageView.image = [myArray objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row*2)+1];
        cell.nameLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]*2;

Comment: sorry my mistake you should replace  [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]*2 with  [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2]. I had updated my answer too.

Comment: @RameshMuthe I know bro but I am just answering what he is asking (just an another approach for solving this problem using single data structure).

Comment: @iDeveloper image working but this is not working cell.nameLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row*2];

Comment: @iDeveloper  bro Please tell me first If any Advantage  using 2D Array (Display images and text in UITableViewCell )or NOT

Comment: @iosstart But this should work? You are adding the title first then immediately after it, it's image (for all data from json)? if so then can you please tell me the error you are facing?

Comment: @iosstart No there is no difference in any approach as all will use same data amount. Only the difference is about good programming tactics, code understanding and error tracking. For this kind of problems the best thing you can use is key value pairs Data structure (dictionaries).